# Why does superglue lose strength at high temperatures?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, temperature

I'm not a chemist. When I superglue my fingers together, by accident, I put them under warm water to peel off the superglue. Why does superglue become less "sticky" at higher temperatures? Is it the water or the temperature?

Comment: Well....... You could always find out yourself...... By supergluing your fingers together and running cold water over them to see whether it helps. ^^

Comment: Use acetone to wash superglue off your fingers. It works great ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is the temperature because as you probably know all kinds of substances get denatured at high temperatures. Another reason could the that the rate of reaction increases after running hot water, therefore taking no effort to take it off. Hope the answer helped!

Comment: Do you actually have any evidence to suggest this is the case. There are also many substances which don't denature at the sort of temperatures we are talking about. Answers based on unqualified speculation are discouraged on chemistry.SE.

Answer (score 1):

The glue is sticky because it is uncured. Water is part of the reactants in the chemical curing. Raising the temperature makes the reaction faster. So you both put the glue in contact with a copious supply of water and raised the temperature which make the curing much faster.

Comment: It's normally suspended in methylethyl ketone or something similar.

Comment: But why does raising the temperature make the superglue easier to peel off my fingers. Does it lose some strength or start to breakdown above a certain temperature?

Comment: It would seem that the glue had not completely cured before you used the water. The water caused the glue to cure fast, before it had time to completely bond with  your skin. Water will not dissolve the cured glue.